# What is an uninegative ligand

Tags: biochemistry, coordination-compounds

I can't find a simple definition via google. All I get are research papers, that I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it just means the charge of the ligand is -1.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unipositive

Cyanide qualifies, ETDA does not.

Anyway, the word is [on its way out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uninegative%2Cunipositive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuninegative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunipositive%3B%2Cc0). "Monoanionic" [seems to be more popular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand#Examples_of_common_ligands_(by_field_strength)).